# Combined grammar ANTLR option filter

Tags: filter, antlr, grammar, lexer

I have a combined grammar (lexer and parser on the same file). How do I set the

```
filter = true
```

to the lexer?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Clarify what Bart said in his answer:

```
The options{filter=true;} only works in lexer-grammars. You will need to define a parser- and lexer grammar in two separate files:
```

You don't actually need to put the lexer and parser in 2 separate files.  You just need to put the filter rule in the lexer grammar.  Both the lexer and the parser grammars **can** be in the same file.

Though Bart's advice of putting them in seperate files is the approach I normally use.

So to take an example you can do this in a single file

### Single file with parser and lexer Grammar.g

```
parser grammar FooParser;

parse
:  Number+ EOF
;

lexer grammar FooLexer;

options{filter=true;}

Number
:  '0'..'9'+
;
```

Note how the filter rule is in the lexer class definition but the lexer and parser are in the same file.

Comment: Note: putting both in the same file no longer works in ANTLR4.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. The `options{filter=true;}` only works in lexer-grammars. You will need to define a parser- and lexer grammar in two separate files (**EDIT**: no, they can be put in one file, see chollida's answer):

### FooParser.g

```
parser grammar FooParser;

parse
  :  Number+ EOF
  ;
```

### FooLexer.g

```
lexer grammar FooLexer;

options{filter=true;}

Number
  :  '0'..'9'+
  ;
```

Combining these lexer and parser will result in a parser that will only parse the strings in a file (or string) consisting of digits.

Note that ANTLR plugins or ANTLRWorks might complain because because the lexer rule(s) is/are not visible to it, but generating a lexer and partser on the command line:

```
java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool FooLexer.g 
java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool FooParser.g
```

works fine.

Answer (score 0):

just, instead of adding **parser grammar yourGrammar** and **lexer grammar yourLexer** to your parser and lexer files respectevely, add **grammar yourGrammarAndLExer** to the beginning of your combined file ^^